# Chrome Extension: yql API ERROR: Content Security

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, yql, yahoo-api

I am trying to make a call to yql api. But get an error: I have the following

```
Manfiest.json:
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'", 

Error:
Refused to load the script 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where…withkeys&callback=jQuery20208888747137971222_1400373036635&_=1400373036638' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".'
```

I tried doing it w/o having the "content_security_policy"
But I would still get an error.

The code to do the call:

```
yqlAPI = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + ' &format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=?';

$.getJSON(yqlAPI, function(r){
$.each(r.query.results.li, function(){ 
  if(typeof this.font !== 'undefined')
      {        
        gogoAnime1.push([this.a.href,this.font.content]);

      }
});
gotFollowersOfA(gogoAnime1);});
```

I have been looking in the 
CSP (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script)
But I don't understand what I have to add to my manifest.json. To make it work all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if that's because of requesting an external object.

[Content Security Policy (CSP) - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script)

> If you have a need for some **external JavaScript or object resources**, you can relax the policy to a limited extent by **whitelisting** secure origins from which scripts should be accepted.

so adjust it accordingly, manfiest.json:

```
"content_security_policy": 
       "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self' https://query.yahooapis.com/"
```

And you'll need to use HTTPS origin:

> As man-in-the-middle attacks are both trivial and undetectable over **HTTP, those origins will not be accepted**. Currently, we allow whitelisting origins with the following schemes: **HTTPS, chrome-extension, and chrome-extension-resource.**

Comment: I tried what you said. But I got the following instead
http://gyazo.com/c8909bf62f0fe22170e05ec5809bfe45

Comment: @user3537288 you need to use https. http sources is not accepted. yql is available in https. can you try the updated answer? thanks

Comment: OMG! It worked. I had to
   "script-src 'self' https://query.yahooapis.com/; object-src 'self' "
Thank you so much!
I didn't know that I could make the call in https. So I just changed it in my js and it worked!

Comment: That's great! I thought it should be object-src, not script-src. But anyway thanks for accepting!